# IOS on device debugging the sample code provided by Realm not working with Chrome dev tool

Tags: react-native, realm, react-devtools

Strictly followed the description listed on [Realm's website](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/)

- react-native init myproj
- cd myproj
- npm install
- npm install --save realm
- react-native link realm

now running `npm list` to verify some versions

- react@16.3.1
- react-native@0.55.4
- realm@2.8.1

Now modify the shipped App.js based on the "Number of dogs" example in Realm's Getting Started page (directly replace the class body).

Now open myproj.xcodeproj in XCode(v9.4), fix the signing error. Make sure there's no other running bundler thread. Choose the ipad mini that's connected in xcode and hit 'build and run'

Once the app is loaded in the ipad mini, I can see

```
 Number of dogs in theis Realm: 1
```

which means Realm is loaded and working correctly. Now shake the ipad mini and tap on the "Debug JS Remotely" menu, I got this error in red background:

```
Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':Failed to load
'http://[IP_of_the_IPAD_mini]:8083/create_session'
```

Chrome React Native Debugger says `"Status: Debugger session #10000 active"`, so it's connected to the ipad mini.

Did the same test on my iphone 7, but got the same error. I do need on device debugging because our project needs to use the camera of the device. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found some clues in [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1787)

to fix the issue, open RealmReact.mm file, search for

> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

and change that line to

```
[response setValue:@"*" forAdditionalHeader:@"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"];
```